# Programmatically setTextColor of widget on based on user input

Tags: android, android-widget, textcolor

I want to make a clock widget where in from its app user can set the `textColor` according to their wish.
So I want to change the TextClock's text color dynamically and programmatically on users click.

I tried using the simple `setTextColor()` method but there is no such method for setting text color of widget.
Below is the code I tried but it crashed the app on user click(touch).

I expect that the color of text changes on user's touch(that can be on any `Button` or `ImageView`).

```
package com.example.demowidget;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextClock;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextClock tctClock;
ImageView imgIcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
imgIcon = findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
tctClock = findViewById(R.id.tctClock);
imgIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {                    
                   tctClock.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
});


}
}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

<TextClock
android:id="@+id/tctClock"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="@drawable/widget_back"
android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textColor="#11AB6B"
android:textSize="36sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your code too

Comment: add your error code

Comment: error code means the code or the error coming in logcat?

Comment: imgIcon = findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
tctClock = findViewById(R.id.tctClock);
imgIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

                tctClock.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        });

thats the code and below is the error:
** Process: com.example.demowidget, PID: 1944
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.TextClock.getBackground()**

Comment: add your full activity code as I doubt you haven't initialized your tctClock textview

Comment: paste your xml code

Answer (score 0):

you can try for this..

first add you color in color.xml file

`<color name="your_color">#094D92</color>`

and replace this line--

```
tctClock.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#094D92"));
```

to

```
tctClock.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color))
```

Comment: gives the same error:

Process: com.example.demowidget, PID: 26229
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextClock.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: check your TextClock and ImageView ID's in main_activity xml file

Comment: i checked them, they are perfectly matching.

Comment: You don't have an imageview in the layout. Can you post the xml file

Comment: you have missed the ImageView in Xml file

Comment: @rohit i have kept that imageView in MainActivity's xml from where i want my user to click the input(that maybe image or button).